# Why do Perl variables need to start with $, %,@ (sigils)?

Tags: perl, variables

Why do Perl variables need to start with different characters (sigils)?

- Scalar variables start with `$`
- Hashes start with `%`
- Arrays start with `@`

Why are they like this?

Comment: Short answer: they don’t. Consider arrays and hashes. That said, the question is confusing. Care to clarify?

Comment: Are you asking why these particular sigils have been chosen (as opposed to three different ones)? Or why there are sigils at all?

Comment: I asked with about only sigils , then i realized my self why other varialble also have like that . so i asked about all ?

Comment: Untangled: *"I only asked about sigils, but then I realized why other variables also have it like that. So I asked about all."* Though it still doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

When I started out using Perl it was explained to me that these characters were chosen because:

- `$` looked a bit like an 's' so that was for **s**calars,
- `@` has an 'a' in the middle so that was for **a**rrays, and
- `%` was for hashes because it looked like a key-value pair divided by a slash.

Comment: Yes, the Camel book tells the same story. Or at least, it doesn't say they were actually chosen because of those reasons, but that you could remember better what they stand for with those mnemonics.

Comment: I also think % looks a little like a "H" for hash if you use a lot of poetic license.

Answer (score 36):

This is because Perl uses [sigils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)):

> In computer programming, a sigil
>   (pronounced /'sɪdʒ.ɪl/ or /'sɪg.ɪl/;
>   plural sigilia or sigils) is a symbol
>   attached to a variable name, showing
>   the variable's datatype or scope. The
>   term was first applied to Perl usage
>   by Philip Gwyn in 1999 to replace the
>   more cumbersome "funny character in
>   front of a variable name". The name is
>   based on the word meaning a magical
>   symbol (see sigil (magic)).

Answer (score 23):

Several reasons are [explained by Larry Wall](http://books.google.com/books?id=oh8lz4A3sUsC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54) et al in *"[Programming Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_Perl)"*:

> Within any given namespace [...] every variable type has its own subnamespace, determined by the funny character. You can, without fear of conflict, use the same name for a scalar variable, an array, or a hash (or, for that matter, a filehandle, a subroutine matter, a label or your pet llama.)
>
> [...]
>
> Like most computer languages, Perl has a list of reserved words that it recognizes as special keywords. However, because variable names always start with a funny character, reserved words don't actually conflict with variable names.

Comment: This makes Perl a Lisp 4 (or 5 if you count the *GLOB)

Comment: Namespace protection is a major benefit of sigils, IMO. ++!

Comment: Doesn't the fact that you can also use variables in different "contexts" make things terribly confusing?  Doesn't this make using the same name for different variables impossible?

Comment: @temp2290 No. Consider `@arr` and `$arr`, they are two different variables. When, for example, you are using `@arr` in a scalar context, you are either accessing a single element: `my $element = $arr[1]` or the length of the array: `my $length = @arr;`. It both cases they are easily distinguished from the scalar variable `$arr`. If `$arr` was a scalar reference to an array, you could do `my $element = $arr->[0];` and `$length = @$arr;`. IMHO at least those are all easily distinguished.

Comment: @cftarnas: I'm hoping that there are multiple errors in your comment rather than that being the correct usage of the language.  I don't really know because I am just starting learn Perl.  Anyway, if your goal was to demonstrate that Perl's use of sigils is not confusing, I don't think you have succeeded.  Perhaps people who have *already* master Perl would disagree with me.

Comment: @nobar Perl is confusing at the beginning, no discussion.

Answer (score 12):

From *[Natural Language Principles in Perl](http://www.wall.org/%7Elarry/natural.html)*:

> English uses number and word order, with vestiges of a case system in the pronouns: "The man looked at the men, and they looked back at him." It's perfectly clear in that sentence who is doing what to whom. Similarly, Perl has number markers on its nouns; that is, $dog is one pooch, and @dog is (potentially) many. So $ and @ are a little like "this" and "these" in English.

Answer (score 11):

- Because Perl was intended to replace shell scripts, and variables in shell start with `$`.
- To distinguish between scalars (`$`), arrays (`@`) and hashes (`%`).

Comment: I wouldn't say perl was intended to replace shell scripts and so kept the `$` sigil (POSIX shell variable are actually initialized without a `$`) - the benefit of the `$` sigil is you can use/interpolate variables without too much context-switching trickery in your code e.g. `echo "the value of variable foo is $foo"` (as opposed to `System.out.println("the value of foo is" + foo)` and that's as far as perl and shell share the commonality. Perl's `$` sigil is more to your second point (denoting variable type/use).

Answer (score 2):

Not all of them do. Some start with % (hashes) or with @ (arrays).

It is a design decision to mark them as variables and also denote their type.

Note that you can have both a `$abc` and a `%abc`.

Check out a [tutorial on Perl variables](http://www.cgi101.com/class/ch2/text.html).

Comment: The sigils don't denote type. They denote how you are treating the thingy. For example, $abc[1] is still using an array variable even though there is a $ out front.

Comment: That inconsistency is going to be fixed in Perl6, where you write @abc[1] to access the second element in the array @abc.

Comment: Assuming any of us live long enough to see a full release of Perl 6.

Comment: @David: a valid concern. I think Ray Kurzweil is working on that problem. ;-)

Comment: @David Thornley:  Hopefully you still be around come Spring 2010 then! (http://www.h-online.com/open/Perl-6-due-in-spring-2010-some-of-it-anyway--/news/113956)

Comment: @Thilo:  Its not an inconsistency though. However Larry Wall conceded  that it was confusing to "beginners" hence changed its semantics in Perl6.