# Seeing value of Perl variable created at runtime

Tags: perl, runtime, display

My code is below:

```
use strict;

my $store = 'Media Markt';
my $sentence = "I visited [store]";

# Replace characters "[" and "]"
$sentence =~ s/\[/\$/g;
$sentence =~ s/\]//g;

print $sentence;
```

I see following at screen:

> I visited $store

Is it possible to see following? I want to see value of $store:

> I visited Media Markt

Comment: `my $store = 'Media Markt'; 
my $sentence = "I visited $store"; 
print $sentence;`

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1091634/632407

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be thinking of using a string, `'store'`, in order to build a variable name, `$store`. This gets to the subject of [symbolic references](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references), and you [do not want to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1298392/4653379) go there.

One way to do what you want is to build a hash that relates such strings to corresponding variables. Then capture the bracketed strings in the sentence and replace them by their hash values

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $store = 'Media Markt';
my $time  = 'morning';

my %repl = ( store => $store, time => $time );

my $sentence = "I visited [store] in the [time]";

$sentence =~ s/\[ ([^]]+) \]/$repl{$1}/gex;

print "$sentence\n";
```

This prints the line `I visited Media Markt in the morning`

The regex captures anything between `[ ]`, by using the [negated character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes) `[^]]` (any char other than `]`), matched one-or-more times (`+`). Then it replaces that  with its value in the hash, using `/e` to evaluate the replacement side as an expression. Since brackets are matched as well they end up being removed.  The `/x` allows spaces inside, for readibilty.

For each string found in brackets there must be a key-value pair in the hash or you'll get a warning. To account for this, we can provide an alternative

```
$sentence =~ s{\[ ([^]+) \]}{$repl{$1}//"[$1]"}gex;
```

The [`defined-or` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) (`//`) puts back `"[$1]"` if `$repl{$1}` returns `undef` (no key `$1` in the hash, or it has `undef` value). Thus strings which have no hash pairs are unchanged. I changed the delimiters to `s{}{}` so that `//` can be used inside.

This does not allow nesting (like `[store [name]]`), does not handle multiline strings, and has other limitations. But it should work for reasonable cases.

Comment: OP may go with just an array of objects If she thinks about dynamically added code.

Comment: @paveljurca  I completely agree that there are other ways to pursue what seems to be the idea, and that OO approach would be good.

Answer (score 2):

As I told you on the Perl Programmers Facebook group, this is very similar to one of the answers in the Perl FAQ.

> [How can I expand variables in text strings?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-expand-variables-in-text-strings%3F)
>
> If you can avoid it, don't, or if you can use a templating system, such as Text::Template or Template Toolkit, do that instead. You might even be able to get the job done with `sprintf` or `printf`:
>
> ```
> my $string = sprintf 'Say hello to %s and %s', $foo, $bar;
> ```
>
> However, for the one-off simple case where I don't want to pull out a full templating system, I'll use a string that has two Perl scalar variables in it. In this example, I want to expand $foo and $bar to their variable's values:
>
> ```
> my $foo = 'Fred';
> my $bar = 'Barney';
> $string = 'Say hello to $foo and $bar';
> ```
>
> One way I can do this involves the substitution operator and a double `/e` flag. The first `/e` evaluates `$1` on the replacement side and turns it into `$foo`. The second `/e` starts with `$foo` and replaces it with its value. `$foo`, then, turns into 'Fred', and that's finally what's left in the string:
>
> ```
> $string =~ s/(\$\w+)/$1/eeg; # 'Say hello to Fred and Barney'
> ```
>
> The `/e` will also silently ignore violations of strict, replacing undefined variable names with the empty string. Since I'm using the `/e` flag (twice even!), I have all of the same security problems I have with `eval` in its string form. If there's something odd in `$foo`, perhaps something like `@{[ system "rm -rf /" ]}`, then I could get myself in trouble.
>
> To get around the security problem, I could also pull the values from a hash instead of evaluating variable names. Using a single `/e`, I can check the hash to ensure the value exists, and if it doesn't, I can replace the missing value with a marker, in this case ??? to signal that I missed something:
>
> ```
> my $string = 'This has $foo and $bar';
> my %Replacements = (
>     foo  => 'Fred',
>     );
> # $string =~ s/\$(\w+)/$Replacements{$1}/g;
> $string =~ s/\$(\w+)/
>             exists $Replacements{$1} ? $Replacements{$1} : '???'
>             /eg;
> print $string;
> ```

And the actual (but **really** not recommended - for the reasons explained in the FAQ above) answer to your question is:

```
$sentence =~ s/\[(\w+)]/'$' . $1/ee;
```